# Cannot create file to Stripe. Get error Only plainfile resource streams are supported

Tags: laravel, object, amazon-s3, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create image which stored in Amazon S3 to Stripe, but I got a problem while creating file.
This is my code used to create file to Stripe

```php
use Stripe\File;
...
$fp = fopen($filePath, 'r');
return File::create([
    'file' => $fp,
    'purpose' => 'identity_document'
], $this->stripeOptions());
```

Error was thrown when I tried to created image to Stripe.

```php
Stripe\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Only plainfile resource streams are supported in C:\xampp\htdocs\ABCD\vendor\stripe\stripe-php\lib\ApiRequestor.php:407
```

The error said that, Stripe only support `plainfile resource streams`, and when I tried `dd()` result from `fopen()` it return a `stream resource` object.

```php
stream resource @1003 ▼
  crypto: array:4 [▼
    "protocol" => "TLSv1.2"
    "cipher_name" => "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256"
    "cipher_bits" => 128
    "cipher_version" => "TLSv1.2"
  ]
  timed_out: false
  blocked: true
  eof: false
  wrapper_data: array:11 [▼
    0 => "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
    1 => "x-amz-id-2: zp14jBOfTbvgv27M4EZXZDhYgmwhHgsADCpcKwSCh0y4s0eMKfeC7DMjXBEzClrGUC+lbZ7RGFU="
    2 => "x-amz-request-id: 8W1S1K0Q2J5W9ZBM"
    3 => "Date: Tue, 13 Oct 2020 06:11:42 GMT"
    4 => "Last-Modified: Tue, 13 Oct 2020 06:11:34 GMT"
    5 => "ETag: "263820eaa58f3a5ddc2dc504732839ca""
    6 => "Accept-Ranges: bytes"
    7 => "Content-Type: image/jpeg"
    8 => "Content-Length: 187383"
    9 => "Server: AmazonS3"
    10 => "Connection: close"
  ]
  wrapper_type: "http"
  stream_type: "tcp_socket/ssl"
  mode: "r"
  unread_bytes: 0
  seekable: false
  uri: "https://vetvideo.s3.amazonaws.com/admin/verification/1602569479_product2.jpg"
  options: []
}
```

I've tried to search `plain object` and got several question like this but it wasn't solved yet.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the source of the file is on `vetvideo.s3`, you can't upload via a URL directly. You have to download the file itself to your server, and then upload it to Stripe using a File object in PHP like so, using the new service oriented calls [1] in PHP.

```
$fp = fopen('/path/to/a/local/file.jpg', 'r');
$stripe->files->create([
  'purpose' => 'identity_document',
  'file' => $fp
]);
```

[1] https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/wiki/Migration-to-StripeClient-and-services-in-7.33.0#client-and-services

Comment: This is correct. Stripe needs a file, not a stream. You should be using the Storage facade when interacting with S3

Comment: @v3nkman, Thank for your reply. I just want to make sure that there is no way to create File on Stripe without store file on server?

Comment: @v3nkman, And I just want to know, you said that I cann't upload via a URL directly if my file is on ```vetvideo.s3```. Is this like an exception? Do you have any reference document for this? I just have worked with Stripe and document from Stripe seems too much with me.

Comment: @CodeJunkie, I've tried to use ```Storage::disk('s3')->get()``` , but it throws error said that it's not kind of object which Stripe required. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Download the files to a tmp directory, once that's complete, upload it, then delete the tmp file :)

Comment: @codeJunkie, I'm looking for a solution without saving file to server, but it seem, this is only possible solution for now. I'll try this. Thanks a lots.

Comment: @simpsons3 Sure thing! Yes the file needs to be a local file on disk, this is confirmed on this document : https://stripe.com/docs/file-upload#uploading-a-file

Comment: @v3nkman, it give me a lot of information. I've tried your suggestion and it worked. Thanks!